# Utilizando um diretório raiz no include do NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

Estou aprendendo NodeJS e eu comecei a criar um projeto só pra se acostumar a desenvolver com ele, porém, estou incomodado com a quantidade de `../../../../../` utilizado ao incluir um código. Como posso utilizar a pasta raiz da minha aplicação como referência do path?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
__dirname
```

Isso lhe dá o caminho do arquivo atualmente em execução

```
__filename
```

Este é o caminho absoluto do arquivo do módulo atual

exemplo

```
console.log(__filename);
// Prints: /Users/mjr/example.js
console.log(__dirname);
// Prints: /Users/mjr
```

Comment: Não resolve meu problema, eu queria algum jeito de utilizar a pasta raiz do meu projeto.

Comment: ja tentou var appRoot = require('app-root-path');
var myModule = require(appRoot + '/lib/my-module.js');

Comment: Consegui dar um jeito aqui, valeu.